# Error in TSQL aggregate error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to count the number of `etape` an Employee work in a project

My table temps are:

Temps:

```
noProjet
noEtape
noEmploye
annee
mois
jrsHm
```

My query is

```
select 
    t.noEmploye, t.NoProjet, c.count
from 
    temps t
inner join 
    (select 
         noProjet, noEtape, count(*) as count
     from 
         temps
     group by 
         noProjet) c on t.noProjet = c.noProjet
order by 
    noEmploye
```

Error I get is

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'temps.noEtape' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory. Remove `noEtape` column from subquery. If column is not in the group list you can not select it unless you apply some aggregations to that column:

```
select t.noEmploye, t.NoProjet, c.count
from temps t

inner join (select noProjet, count(*) as count
from temps

group by noProjet ) c on t.noProjet = c.noProjet
order by noEmploye
```

Or:

```
select t.noEmploye, t.NoProjet, c.count
from temps t

inner join (select noProjet, max(noEtape) as noEtape, count(*) as count
from temps

group by noProjet ) c on t.noProjet = c.noProjet
order by noEmploye
```

Comment: it doesnt count the good thing it has to count of 'etape' the employee work into a projet

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select distinct
  noEmploye,
  noProjet,
  sum(noEtape) over (
    partition by noProjet
  ) as EtapesdeProjet
from Temps
order by noEmploye
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this by using next query:

```
select 
    t.noEmploye, 
    t.NoProjet, 
    c.count
from temps t
    inner join (select noProjet, noEtape, count(*) as count from temps group by noProjet, noEtape) as c 
        on t.noProjet = c.noProjet
order by noEmploye
```

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'noProjet'.                                                                                         on the c.noProjet

Comment: I fixed up the query.